# Is it possible to load multiple texture files using three.js .obj file format loader?

Tags: textures, three.js

I have .obj files each with several texture files. Does three.js comes out of the box with loading multiple textures for .obj files? Is there some example code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OBJLoader` doesn't load textures or materials yet.

Comment: Wait..I did not get what you mean.


"OBJLoader doesn't loaded textures os materials yet." 

OBJLoader doesn't **load** textures **of** materials ?

Surely though, I've seen three.js examples using .obj files with texture.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant to write "doesn't load textures or materials yet".

Comment: Ah OK thanks. Do you mind if I ask if there's a plan with a timeline for it?

Comment: Is the preferred way of loading textures / materials from OBJ's to run them through the convert_obj_three.py script?  I haven't been able to get any of my textures to work that way either.